# 2 $wpdb queries causing error Table 'wp_postmeta' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE'

Tags: database, wpdb, sql

I am attempting to run an SQL query on the post meta twice to update 2 values, I get the error:

**Table 'wp_postmeta' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data**

I have attempted to combine the queries into 1, surely you can run 2 queries to the same table?

```
<?php
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
            SET meta_value = %s
            WHERE meta_key = %s
            AND meta_value = %s
            IN (
                SELECT post_id
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
                WHERE meta_value = %s
            )",
        $var1,
        '_regular_price',
        $var2
    )
);

$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
            SET meta_value = %s
            WHERE meta_key = %s
            AND meta_value = %s
            IN (
                SELECT post_id
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
                WHERE meta_value = %s
            )",
        $var3,
        '_other_price',
        $var4
    )
);
```

Comment: I've googled that this is a common MySQL problem. People suggests to use `join`.

Comment: not sure what is the wordpress aspect in this question. This is a mysql error which tells you your request is bad. If you need an explanation why, stackoverflow is probably a better place.